# Meshed and skinned rag doll

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I've been trying to make a meshed rag doll, but I just can't figure out how. I need to be able to put an actual texture on it, as I'm using this in a VFX shot. Any ideas?

Edit: I followed this tutorial for making the rag doll. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtaG8EqN_nw
And I haven't started on the VFX shot, I've just been doing some tests. I can't figure out how to get a mesh to deform with the bones.

Comment: I don't think that this would be classified as texturing because I can do that already, I need to know how to get a mesh to deform as the rag doll bones do. Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.